# Get Backend name when I use VideoCapture

Tags: opencv, video-capture

OpenCV: 2.4.11, Visual Studio 2013

I try to get Backend name when I use VideoCapture but failed.
I succeeded with OpenCV 4.5.4 (with Visual Studio 2019), but 'getBackendName' seems doesn't exist in the OpenCV 2.4.11.
Here is the error message.

error C2039: 'getBackendName' : is not a member of 'cv::VideoCapture'

Is there any way that I can get backend name with OpenCV 2.4.x?

Thank you in advance!
Please let me know if you need any further information.

Best regards,
JESuh

Comment: you can *set* it when creating the VideoCapture. apart from that, no. if you need that, you'll need to abandon the unsupported version.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment :) I tried to set it as below and wish it works well..I wanted to use direct show. Thank you again!
 VideoCapture cap(1); // or 700, 701 directly without opening.
 cap.open(700); // for the first USB camera, and 701 for the second one.

Comment: use `0 + CAP_DSHOW` or `1 + CAP_DSHOW` for camera index 0 or 1 respectively. pass to the constructor. the open() call should not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! :) It works very well.